# Using generics in an abstract method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm facing a compiler error and I'm having a hard time figuring out why the compiler cannot understand what I'm trying to do! :)

It starts with an abstract base class:

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract Task<T> DoSomething<T>() where T : MyObject;
}
```

Note that I'm specifying a constraint for `T`, which should be of type `MyObject`.

Now I try to derive from `Base` this way:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    protected override Task<T> DoSomething<T>()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<MyObject>(new MyObject());
    }
}
```

which looks valid to me because I'm returning a `Task<MyObject>`, which respects the constraint.

But the compiler complains on the implementation of DoSomething, says that

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyObject>`' to '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>`'

I cannot reinforce the constraint in the derived class, so I'm really wondering how to sort this out!

Comment: FromResult<MyObject>(...).Cast<T>()?

Comment: Classes are not covariant in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not constraining it to only `MyObject`, but to anything derived from `MyObject`. It you created `MyOtherObject` from it and called `DoSomething<MyOtherObject>()`, it would try to return a `Task<MyObject>`, not `Task<MyOtherObject>`. It isn't possible to implicitly cast `Task<MyObject>`to `Task<MyOtherObject>`. So the code isn't valid and doesn't compile.

As the code currently stands, the generics are not needed. The signature:

```
protected abstract Task<MyObject> DoSomething();
```

meets your needs.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the combination of generics + base class doesn't make sense here. Actually there are indeed many sub-classes of MyObject, and the goal was to use generics so that the caller of DoSomething could specify which sub-class he expects. How would you implement that requirement?

Comment: @ThomasWeiss I haven't tried this, so there may be mistakes, but how about if you change Base to `protected abstract Task<T> DoSomething<T>() where T : MyObject, new;` and Derived to `return Task.FromResult<T>(new T());`. This should work for any derived class that has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: That would work indeed, but the type's constructor was just used here to demonstrate the issue, I'm actually doing different stuff in the method depending on the expected returned type. I think the basic "problem" is that you can't assign a Task<MyOtherObject> to a Task<MyObject>, thus limiting what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When you override you override it all. In this case the constraint over T is not longer valid.

Comment: @undefined, Why ? It the same as accepted answer by David but less elaborated.

Comment: Because constraints over T do hold when you override. Or am I misreading your answer?